# an equivalent of 'gamenet'

Tags: word-request

There are these venues in my neighborhood with computers and sometimes consoles in which kids play video games especially team video games such as Counter Strike. We call these venues *gamenets* although I can't get google hits on it. I thought maybe the closest word would be [video arcade](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amusement_arcade) but it seems a video arcade includes much more games than just video games. What's the word for such venues?

Comment: Is playing video games the only activity at a _gamenet_?

Comment: @Lars Mekes Yes, the usual thing you see is two rows of computers each in the different side of the room, across from each other. Each team takes one side, and then the war begins.

Comment: Well you'd call it a LAN party once upon a time.  The necessity to be on a LAN network is not so incredibly important nowadays, but you still might hear the term used as such.

Comment: @Neil A LAN party is an occurrence, not a location where you can always play video games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Internet café](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_caf%C3%A9), or cybercafé, comes to mind when reading your description.

While these are not exclusively for playing video games, it is one of the main activities happening there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not certain what it could really be as I'm not a native speaker but I often come across the term "**computer club**" where people surf the web, work, play games (single player or multiplayer), or do whatever else they want.